# DBUS Java: How to export properties on DBus interface

Tags: java, dbus

I am trying to use Dbus java library for a project, while I can easily found good tutorials/docs on how to create methods and signals for DBus interfaces, I could not get any helpful documentation which describe me in detail about exporting properties into DBus interfaces.

One thing I tried is, implementing the get(), set(), and getAll() methods of org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties interfaces, but this only added a separate property interface with the three methods on my DBus interface path.

To better describe what I exactly wanted do, below I used org.freedesktop.NetworkManager interface as an example.

This is the structure of NetworkManager interface on D-Feet, and I wanted to add/include some properties on my Java based DBus interface in the way it is included here on Network Manager properties.

```
/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager
  > org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectasble
  > org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer
  > org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties
  > org.freedesktop.NetworkManager
    > Methods
      // Network manager methods….
    > Properties
     //Network manager Properties
    > Signals
     //Network manager Signals
```

Hope I will get some help.
Thanks